# using class instance on two classes..c++

Tags: c++, oop

I basically do not know how to ask this question, I am fairly new to c++...anyway my problem is, I am trying to create this vendingmachine class and this user class, the user needs to have access to the insertCoins method and makePurchase methods from vendingMachine.cpp I tried creating an instance of the class vending machine inside the method calls in user.cpp as it is here, but when I try to list the items in vending machine obviously the list is untouched because theinstance I create inside the method calls in user.cpp are just temporary...how would I get a global instance so that I use  it within user.cpp while using it within vending machine inside main.cpp...

```
#include "user.h"
#include "VendingMachine.h"

user::user(){
}

user::~user(){

}

void user::makePurchase(int choice){
    VendingMachine vm;
    vm.purchaseProduct(choice);
}

void user::insertCoins(double coin){
    VendingMachine vm;
    vm.insertCoins(coin);
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
#include "VendingMachine.h"
#include "machineOperator.h"
#include "user.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

VendingMachine vm = VendingMachine();
user u = user();
vm.listProducts();
cout << endl;
u.insertCoins(1.0);
u.insertCoins(1.0);
u.makePurchase(2);
vm.listProducts();
cout << endl;

return 0;

 }
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
    /*
 * user.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 12, 2014
 *      Author: Andrey
 */

#ifndef USER_H_
#define USER_H_

class user {

public:
    user();
    ~user();
    void makePurchase(int);
    void insertCoins(double);
};

#endif /* USER_H_ */
```

Answer (score 4):

It is natural to assume that a user can purchase from and insert coin to many different vending machines.

```
void user::makePurchase (VendingMachine &vm, int choice)
{
    vm.purchaseProduct(choice);
}

void user::insertCoins (VendingMachine &vm, double coin)
{
    vm.insertCoins(coin);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me this..."prototype for 'void user::makePurchase(VendingMachine&, int)' does not match any in class 'user' "

Comment: @AndreyArias You have to add it your user declaration (user.h), as you must have done with all your other functions.

Comment: @AndreyArias: I am assuming the first code snippet in your question is the header `#include "machineOperator.h"`. You included the header files: `#include "VendingMachine.h"` and `#include "user.h"` in the main.cpp too. Remove those from there and it will work.

Comment: @pingul: I am pretty sure he has done this. The header includes are wrong.

Comment: @Blacktempel Do you reckon he would get that error message then? Valid point never the less.

Comment: how would that work?? does not make sense, I tried it and it just doesnt let me initialize anything , I did add it in the user.h declaration and still the same thing...there must be a way of doing it from within main.cpp ...

Comment: @pingul: Either this, or he has declared them wrong in his class.

Comment: @AndreyArias: Please add that to your question.

Comment: there...I included the user,h

Comment: @AndreyArias: As I think this is not really an answer (as long as it is not the solution) and I don't want to mess it up as comment... here is it: http://pastebin.com/yjEZwTnq

Comment: gets me this error...:'VendingMachine' has not been declared"

Comment: Use the forward declaration `class VendingMachine;` before your `class user {...};`.

Comment: @AndreyArias If you have questions on including and such (forward declaring etc), have a go at this tutorial: [http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to the VendingMachine in your user and pass it in to the constructor.

user.h

```
class VendingMachine;

class User {
    private:
        VendingMachine* vm;
}
```

user.cc

```
#include "user.h"
#include "vendingmachine.h"

User::User(VendingMachine* vm): vm(vm) {}

void User::makePurchase(int choice){
    vm->purchaseProduct(choice);
}

void User::insertCoins(double coin){
    vm->insertCoins(coin);
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "VendingMachine.h"
#include "machineOperator.h"
#include "user.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    VendingMachine vm = VendingMachine();
    User u = User(&vm);
    vm.listProducts();
    cout << endl;
    u.insertCoins(1.0);
    u.insertCoins(1.0);
    u.makePurchase(2);
    vm.listProducts();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: user534498's reply probably makes more sense with passing the vending machine to the methods.